# BeautifulSoup - dealing with table like website structures|returning dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html, that sort looks like a dictionary:

Manufacturer website: Website,

Headquarters: location, etc
..

Each portion is contained within its own div (so findAll, div class name).

Is there a **elegant** and simple way to extract such code into a dictionary?  Or does one have to iterate over each div, find both text items, and assume that first text item is key of dictionary, and second value is the value of the same dict element.

Sample Site Code:

```
    car = '''
     <div class="info flexbox">
       <div class="infoEntity">
        <span class="manufacturer website">
         <a class="link" href="http://www.ford.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank">
          www.ford.com
         </a>
        </span>
       </div>
       <div class="infoEntity">
        <label>
         Headquarters
        </label>
        <span class="value">
         Dearbord, MI
        </span>
       </div>
       <div class="infoEntity">
        <label>
         Model
        </label>
        <span class="value">
         Mustang
        </span>
       </div>
    '''

car_soup = BeautifulSoup(car, 'lxml')
print(car_soup.prettify())

elements = car_soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'infoEntity')
for x in elements:
    print(x)  ###and then we start iterating over x, with beautiful soup, to find value of each element.
```

Desired output is this

```
expected result result = {'manufacturer website':"ford.com", 'Headquarters': 'Dearborn, Mi', 'Model':'Mustang'}
```

P.S. I've done the non-elegant way a few times at this point, just wondering if I'm missing something, and if there is a better way to do this.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, to keep things more or less generic and simple, you can split out handling of fields with labels and the manufacturer website link:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(car, 'lxml')

car_info = soup.select_one('.info')
data = {
    label.get_text(strip=True): label.find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)
    for label in car_info.select('.infoEntity label')
}
data['manufacturer website'] = car_info.select_one('.infoEntity a').get_text(strip=True)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'Headquarters': 'Dearbord, MI', 
 'Model': 'Mustang', 
 'manufacturer website': 'www.ford.com'}
```

Comment: thank you both for the response.  this short one looks super elegant!  Now i just need to re-implement this throughout the  code :)

Answer (score 2):

The current HTML structure is quite generic, it contains multiple `infoEntity` divs with child content that can be formatted multiple ways. To handle this, you can iterate over `infoEntity` divs and apply formatting object like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
result, label = {}, None
for i in soup(car, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'infoEntity'}):
   for b in i.find_all(['span', 'label']):
      if b.name == 'label':
         label = b.get_text(strip=True)
      elif b.name == 'span' and label is not None:
         result[label] = b.get_text(strip=True)
         label = None
      else:
         result[' '.join(b['class'])] = b.get_text(strip=True)
```

Output:

```
{'manufacturer website': 'www.ford.com', 'Headquarters': 'Dearbord, MI', 'Model': 'Mustang'}
```